# .split from a file and putting it in an array

Tags: python

Im reading a file with some information and each part is separated with a @ however on each line i want it to be a different array so i did this and im not sure why its not working.

```
main_file = open("main_file.txt","r")
main_file_info=main_file.readlines()

test=[]
n=0
for line in main_file_info:
       test[n]=line.split("@")

test=test[n][1:len(test)-1] # to get rid of empty strings at the start and the end 
print(test)# see what comes out 

main_file.close()
```

Comment: Can you show what output are you getting ? Please post a sample of your input file.

Comment: im not getting anythin im getting a error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dominic\Desktop\Homework creator\reading files.py", line 14, in <module>
    test[n]=line.split("@")
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: i added a n=n+1 in the for statment and it still does the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are inserting the output of `line.split("@")` in your list is wrong. Your list is not initialized, hence, you can't simply assign anything to any element of the list. So, what you need to do is this :

```
test.append(line.split("@"))
```

Or, you can initialize your list as below :

```
test = [[]]*(len(main_file_info))
```

Comment: this worked but i still get the empty strings at the start and the end

Comment: it gives me this output : [['', '1', '1', 'A', '3', 'none', '3', '\n'], ['', '2', '2', 'B', '3', '1', '2', '\n']]

Comment: In that case, do this : `new_test = [filter(bool, i) for i in test]`, this would remove empty strings present anywhere from the list. @DominikPraski

Comment: it still comes out with the same output with the empty strings

Comment: and the file looks like this : @1@1@A@3@none@3@ #new line and then :
@2@2@B@3@1@2@

Comment: That's because it's not an empty string, but a `whitespace`, for that, do this : `new_test = [filter(bool, map(lambda x: x.strip(), i)) for i in test]`

Comment: erm i dont know if im doing anything wrong but that still dosent work mate. comes out with the same output as it did before which is: [['', '1', '1', 'A', '3', 'none', '3', '\n'], ['', '2', '2', 'B', '3', '1', '2', '']] and i added what you told me

Comment: also im not sure why the '\n' is in the list

Comment: Try this : `main_file = open("main_info.txt","r")
main_file_info=main_file.readlines()

def rm(list_) :
    return [x for x in list_ if x != '\n' and x != ' ']

test=[]
n=0
for line in main_file_info:
       test.append(rm(line.split("@")))

print test
main_file.close()`

Comment: It WORK. Thanks :) just had to change the ' ' in to a empty '' :P

Comment: No problem, please remember to upvote as well, when you get more than 15 reputation. :)

Comment: yeah ill dont worry,

Answer (score 0):

```
test = [None for _ in range(total)]
# instead of test = []
```

or simply just append to `test`:

```
test.append( line.split("@") )
```